# Webpage stuck in loading in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, loading, freeze, assets, missing-data

My webpage gets stuck in loading in Chrome (the little spinning icon on the page tab, and the mouse cursor also stuck in loading version), but the odd thing is everything in the website displays fine. This doesn't happen in Firefox or IE.

Does anyone have any theory to what's causing it? Is it because some asset doesn't exist? For example:

```
<img src="pic.png">
```

But "pic.png" doesn't exist?

If that's the case how do I check the code to make sure all assets, including css/js/img/sound/video files all exist as linked from the document? My html file is huge, going line by line and checking would take forever.

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Yes I get two errors, both has to do with Meebo. If I delete the Meebo toolbar then I don't get any errors. HOWEVER, even without any errors, the page STILL gets stuck on loading.